# Python dict serialization: get different results from 'same' dict

Tags: python-3.x, serialization

d1 equals d2, but b1 is different b2. 
Is there anyone can explain it ? Great Thanks!

```
    import pickle
    b1 = b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x07\x00\x00\x00clusterq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00unitq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x04u.'
    b2 = b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x07\x00\x00\x00clusterq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00unitq\x03h\x02u.'

    d1 = pickle.loads(b1)
    d2 = pickle.loads(b2)
    print(d1)  
    # {'cluster': 'ALL', 'unit': 'ALL'}
    print(d2)
    # {'cluster': 'ALL', 'unit': 'ALL'}
    print(d1 == d2)
    # True
    pickle.dumps(d1)
    # b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x07\x00\x00\x00clusterq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00unitq\x03X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x04u.'
    pickle.dumps(d2)
    # b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x07\x00\x00\x00clusterq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00ALLq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00unitq\x03h\x02u.'
```